# ggplot: add mathematical expression to different facets in different position

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, annotate, geom-text

I'm trying to add different texts to different facets but since the scales are different, I'd like to position them in the appropriate places for each facet. geom_text allows me to play with the position but couldn't turn the r^2 into a mathematical expression ("2" should be supperscript). Annotate allows me present the mathematical expression but not to place the texts in different positions (get an error message).

Here is a reproducible example:

```
df1=data.frame(x=c(1,10,100), y=c(1,10,100), fct=c("a", "b", "c"))
df2=data.frame(fct=c("a", "b", "c"), r2=c("r^2", "r^2", "r^2"), labs=c(7, 3, 8))
lb <- c(paste("r^2 == ", df2[1,3]), paste("r^2 == ", df2[2,3]),paste("r^2 == ", df2[3,3]))


#option 1 with geom_text
ggplot(df1, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_point(data=df1, aes(x=x, y=y, color=fct))+facet_grid(~fct, scales='free')+geom_text(data=df2, aes(x=c(1, 10, 100), y=25, label=paste(r2,'=',labs), parse=T))

#option 2 with annotate
ggplot(df1, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_point(data=df1, aes(x=x, y=y, color=fct))+facet_grid(~fct, scales='free')+annotate("text", x=1, y=20, label=lb, parse=TRUE)
```

Thanks for the help,

Guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ggplot warns you in the 1st example:

> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: parse

If you put if outside the `aes` mappings, then you'll get:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_point(data=df1, aes(x=x, y=y, color=fct))+
  facet_grid(~fct, scales='free')+
  geom_text(data=df2, aes(x=c(1, 10, 100), y=25, label=paste(r2,'==',labs)), parse=T)
```

[image]

Comment: perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: PS: I didn't get this warning